# Neural Network, Genetic algorithm as an Intrusion detection system

Tags: c#, algorithm, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

Hi I need some help on getting started with creating my first algorithm; I want to create a NN/Genetic Algorithm for use as an Intrusion detection system.

But I’m struggling with some points (never written an algorithm before.)

1. I want to develop in C# would it be possible as a console app? If so, as a precursor how big would the programme roughly be, at its most simplistic form. Is it even possible in c#?
2. How to connect the program to read in data from the network? Also how packets can be converted to readable data for the algorithm.
3. How to get the programme to write rules for snort or some other form of firewall and block what the programme deems as a potential threat. (i.e it spots a threat from No.2 then it writes a rule into the snort rules page blocking that specific traffic)
4. How to track the data. (what its blocked what its observing how it came to that conclusion)
5. Where to place it on the network? (can the programme connect to other algorithms and share data on the same network, would that be beneficial)

If anyone can help start me off in the right direction or explain what other alternatives there are like fuzzy logic etc  and why is it deemed as a black box?

Comment: snort is not a firewall.  It is an intrusion detection system.  Also, it has some ability to generate rules for firewalls just like your idea #3 above, but those rules are coming from snort, not installed into snort.  Snort itself has rules for detection of malicious activity, but it's very unlikely that your NN/GA will develop rules compatible with snort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a console app, and C#, can be used to create a Neural Network. Of course, if you want more visual aspects to the UI, you'll want to use WinForms/WPF/Silverlight etc.. It's impossible to tell how big the program will be as there's not enough information on what you want to do. Also, the size shouldn't really be a problem as long as it's efficient.

I assume this is some sort of final year project? What type of Neural Network are you using? You should read some academic papers /whitepapers on using NN with intrusion detection to get an idea. For example, this [PDF](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/detection/application-neural-networks-intrusion-detection_336) has some information that might help.

You should take this one step at a time. Creating a Neural Network is separate from creating a new rule in Snort. Work on one topic at a time otherwise you'll just get overwhelmed. Considering the hard part will most likely be the NN, you should focus on that first.

It's unlikely anyone's going to go through each step with you as it's quite a large project. Show what you've done and explain where you need help.

Comment: As a starting point, I highly recommend AI-Junkie's site. This will give you a nice overview on NN and Genetic Algorithms. It's vital you understand what they are first as it can be quite confusing when there are so many different types out there: http://ai-junkie.com/

Comment: @Garrith: It's not an either-or sort of thing.  NN are a model structure, while GA are a training mechanism.  Weights in the NN aren't confused with weights in the GA, they are the same parameter.  The GA finds the weights, the NN processes the data, and it's all highly recursive (the GA needs to know how well each set of weights performs when implemented in the NN since this information guides survival of the fittest).

Answer (score 1):

My core realization when I started learning about neural networks is that they are just function approximators. I think that's a crucial thing to keep in mind. Whether you're using genetic algorithms or neural nets (or combining them as mentioned by @Ben Voigt, even though neural networks are typically associated with other training techniques) - what you get in the end is a function where you put in a number of real values and get out a single value.

Keeping this in mind, you can design your program and just think of the network as a black box providing those predictions, on the testing part. During training, think of another black box where you put in pairs of input and output pairs and assume it's gonna get better the more pairs you show to it.

Maybe you find this trivial, but with all the theory and mystic behaviour that's associated with this type of algorithms, I found it reassuring (though a bit disappointing ;) to reduce them to those kinds of boxes.